# User defined function in pytorch GPU python

Tags: pytorch, gpu

is it possible to execute user defined functions in GPU?
I have tried pytorch library to execute in cuda . I shall  give an example what i have tried

```
def mymodule1(x):
        ......
        ......
        ......
        return y

def mymodule2(x):
    ......
    ......
    ......
    return y
def mymodule3(x):
    ......
    ......
    ......
    return y
def mymodule4(x):
    y=mymodule3(x)
    y=mymodule2(y)
    y=mymodule1(y)
    return y
```

my requirement is to run the mymodule4 in GPU.May i assign each variable to cuda.
Thank You

Comment: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple example for converting CPU functions to GPU

```
x=1000
DEVICE = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
y=torch.tensor(x,dtype=torch.float)
gpu_out = mymodule1(y).to(DEVICE)
out_cpu=gpu_out.cpu()
out=out_cpu.numpy()
print(out)
```

But this code will execute in GPU ,but  poor performance compared to CPU. Use this code for multiple tensor arrays . Here is the example

```
dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor # Uncomment this to run on GPU
N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10
# Create random input and output data
x = torch.randn(N, D_in).type(dtype)
y = torch.randn(N, D_out).type(dtype)
# Randomly initialize weights
w1 = torch.randn(D_in, H).type(dtype)
w2 = torch.randn(H, D_out).type(dtype)
gpu_out = mymodule1(x,y).to(DEVICE)
out_cpu=gpu_out.cpu()
out=out_cpu.numpy()
print(out)
```